# How to list all tags for commits which created a set of files in git?

Tags: git

I have a folder with many files and i want to list tags that tag the commits which were used to create these files.

Basically i would need the following output:

- /someFile - v1.0
- /someFile2 - v1.1

*In other words: /someFile first appeared in tag v1.0, /someFile2 first appeared in tag v1.1.*

I'm currently using git log to fetch the commit which created the file:

```
git log --oneline --diff-filter=A -- somefile
```

And afterwards i can use git tag to find the tags that were used for that commit.

```
git tag --contains ISH
```

Is there maybe a way to simplify this?

Comment: "list the git tags that tag those commits that tagged the specific commit..." Huh?

Comment: Ups.. i just updated the text and added an example

Answer (score 0):

Here is something ugly for dos.  I am sure there is something better.

```
for /f "usebackq" %i in (`git log "--pretty=%h" -- somefile`) do git tag --contains %i
```

use double %%'s to put this in a batch file